# Font sizes for responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-size

What is a sensible strategy for font sizing across different viewport sizes? I see three different possible options:

1. Decrease font size as viewport size decreases.
2. Identical font size for all viewport sizes.
3. Increase font size as viewport size decreases.

What would be the best option, and why?

Comment: Are you using px or em?  Best to use em when dealing with fonts.

Comment: Surely it would depend on the site in question? Information-heavy sites would benefit from keeping font sizes fixed, whereas sites with less written information might work better increasing font size as the viewport reduces.

Comment: Keep it the same and use PX.  Let the device do the math for it's particular screen density.  This way, 12px on desktop is 12px on mobile etc.  It will simply look good no matter what.  I use the technique here... http://mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/

Comment: @evilscary, well the question is not about a specific site, but more about the pros and cons of each strategy. For example, I see a lot of responsive site that increase their font size as the viewport decreases and I don't understand why..

Comment: @Lowkase, as I said in an earlier comment, the question is not about a specific site, but lets say I'm using em's.

Comment: @Michael, sorry, your link doesn't work for me..

Comment: @Samuel Sorry, I typed it wrong, khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate

Comment: @Michael, However, just using px has the disadvantage that when text is zoomed your layout could break, as it does when I zoom your site. Which is why I prefer ems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an open ended question - because really, it's down to: what does your content require?

Do your pages have long paragraphs of text? Or are you looking at a home page with lots of headlines?

*In general, when dealing with body text*, I tend to approach things by setting a base font size for mobile/small screen sizes. Then, at greater viewport sizes, increase the font size. What viewport sizes /breakpoints? That depends again on the content. You want to keep an eye on the character count per line of text. When it gets too long, you will need to bump the font size up. This approach is not *device specific* but rather *content specific*.

Also, [keep an eye out for the vw font size unit](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/). Hopefully we'll be able to start using it soon.

Comment: You're right, it's an open ended question, but for simplicities sake: what you're saying is that you prefer to keep the character count per line constant across viewport sizes (barring some other layout or content requirements).

Comment: And also, the vw unit sounds interesting. Sort of like a non-cascading % unit.

Comment: That's a good way to characterize it - I like to maintain a character count *range* across viewport sizes. Usually I shoot for 60-80 characters per line, but that's my preference. Go with your eye first.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `em` or `rem` for font sizes that are used as content text. Let the device decide how to render this text.

If its design-critical text (like headings or nav items) I use `px` values, but its probably fine to still use (`r`)`em`s for this.

If the text needs to scale to fit its container, I've had good luck with a plugin called [fittextJS](http://fittextjs.com/)